# Updating global variable via function

Tags: javascript, function

I've seen this question asked quite a bit, and I've followed all the recommendations but I can't seem to get it to work. My code is pretty simple at the moment, all it's doing is getting an input value from the input field, and updating the global variable. Any help would be great!

```js
const createButton = document.getElementById('create-todo');
const errorOutput = document.getElementById('error-messages');
let taskValue = '';



const getInputValue = () => {
    
    const inputValue = document.getElementById('task-input').value;
    
    if(inputValue === ''){
        errorOutput.innerHTML += `<p>Please Enter A Task</p>`;
    }else{
        taskValue = inputValue;
        
    };

};

createButton.addEventListener('click', getInputValue);

console.log(taskValue);
```

```html
<div id="root">
        <header class="header">
            <h1>To Do List</h1>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
        </header>
        <main class="main">
            <section class="todo-form">
                <input  type="text"
                        placeholder="Type your task..."
                        value = ""
                        id="task-input">
                <button id="create-todo">Add To List</button>
            </section>
            <section id="error-messages"></section>
            <section class="todo-list">
                <ul>
                    <li id="todo-list-item">test item</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="list-buttons">
                    <button id="mark-completed">Mark As Completed</button>
                    <button id="remove-item">Remove Item</button>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="completed-list">
                <h2>Completed Tasks</h2>
            </section>
        </main>
        <footer class="footer">
            <button class="reset-button" id="reset">Clear List</button>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

Comment: What problem do you encounter in your code?

Comment: cosole.log(taskValue); still returns an empty string.

Comment: You need to log the `taskValue` after you've clicked the button. Check it in browser console manually after the button click, it should work.

Comment: That's because that line is executing immediately (before the `click` event has taken place). Move it into the `getInputValue` function so it runs at the right time.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, and it doesn't update the variable after clicking the button

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML

Comment: Can you provide a working, minimal example to show the issue? Your code looks fine.

Comment: _"it doesn't update the variable after clicking the button"_ - please show us what you mean.

Comment: @JohannesH. The code isn't correct. The log fires immediately after assigning the handler, but the handler code hasn't executed yet.

Comment: How do you initialize your code? If your javascript code gets executed before the DOM is complete, your getElementById calls will not return any node.

Comment: @ravikthapliyal Your correct. What I meant was that the code to update the variable seems to be correct.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Understood. That makes sense, the line executing immediately before the click event takes place. I was getting confused because once the event does take place I assumed the log to the console would show the changed variable. I guess not

Comment: See my updated answer for a bit of explanation on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because that line is executing immediately (before the `click` event has taken place). Move it into the `getInputValue` function so it runs at the right time.

Code in JavaScript does not necessarily execute linearly. Functions that are registered as event handlers (callbacks) only run when and if that event occurs, so that code is skipped over until needed. Your `console.log()` exists outside of that, so it is executed right away.

> Yeah I tried that, and it doesn't update the variable after clicking
> the button

Then you have another problem because as you can see below, it works as I describe if you simply move the code you want to run after the button is clicked into the button click handler.

```js
document.getElementById('create-todo').addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(task.value === ''){
        errorOutput.innerHTML += `<p>Please Enter A Task</p>`;
    }else{
        taskValue = task.value;
    }
    console.log(taskValue);  // <-- Works now!
  }
);
const errorOutput = document.getElementById('error-messages');
const task = document.getElementById('task-input');
let taskValue = '';
```

```html
<div id="root">
    <header class="header">
        <h1>To Do List</h1>
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
    </header>
    <main class="main">
        <section class="todo-form">
            <input  type="text"
                    placeholder="Type your task..."
                    value = ""
                    id="task-input">
            <button id="create-todo">Add To List</button>
        </section>
        <section id="error-messages"></section>
        <section class="todo-list">
            <ul>
                <li id="todo-list-item">test item</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="list-buttons">
                <button id="mark-completed">Mark As Completed</button>
                <button id="remove-item">Remove Item</button>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="completed-list">
            <h2>Completed Tasks</h2>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">
        <button class="reset-button" id="reset">Clear List</button>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @ScottMarcus that makes a lot of sense. My assumptions of how Javascript would behave was incorrect.